# Nodejs + Express vs Django: Choosing the best suitable backend component for given requirements

Tags: node.js, django, web-applications, data-visualization, real-time-data

I'm trying to build a software architecture for my web development. The main requirements of the website are as follows:

- visualize real-time data
- carry out machine learning analysis
- Report visualization information via Email or SMS

The concept for such an web application consists of a database, a backend and a frontend component. I have already selected a time series database.

Despite my research, I cannot determine which backend component best meets the requirements: Nodejs + Expressjs or Django. My programming knowledge in Javascript and Python is on the same level.

Why Node:

- its Single Threaded Event Loop Model for real-time web applications
- same programming language for selecting a javascript framework on the frontend-side (but python for machine learning analysis)
- More flexibility than Django due to its MTV pattern
- (usually) less execution time than python-Code

Why Django:

- Django Channels for real-time web applications
- python language in backend, frontend and for data analysis
- quicker development process because of the language simplicity
- more secure due to its build-in security tools

**Question:**
Are there any other technical arguments why I should consider choosing Nodejs or Django or any arguments for not choosing one of them?

Answer (score 4):

1. Well Django is also very flexible and powerful in the sense that you have to write less boilerplate code and gives you many solutions out of the box like admin panel, authentication and many more...
2. yes its true nodejs is fast as compared to django but tell me how fast? does it really matter?
3. Django also has concept like celery which are used for background tasks such as sending mails. A possible nodejs threading alternative.
4. In nodejs you have websockets while in django you have channels
5. You can do machine learning in both, nodejs also has tenserflow support and many other libs.

Conclusion: In my opinion you should go either with Django, laravel or Rails or something mature like that, Reason is nodejs web frameworks are pretty young in the market, where as django has been for more than 20 years now I guess, and same for laravel etc. Express is lot of boiler plate code, and as for nestjs, its also pretty young.

Hope my suggestion help you. Personally I also started with nodejs and now switched to Django. I am not saying nodejs is bad, its awesome but Time matters, if you want to develop stuff fast, then nodejs is not a good solution.